# How to install Deepin Desktop Environment in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, appearance

Every post on internet to install DDE on Ubuntu is same as this:
https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/install-deepin-desktop-environment-derivatives-ubuntu/

I have tried even the PPA but not working: leaeasy/dde
Please explain if there is some other way to do it.
If there is no otherway then how can I install DDE from source, which is here:
https://github.com/linuxdeepin/

Comment: There was a time when Deepin was based on Ubuntu and installing its DE in other variants was somehow easy. Now is based on Debian and the PPA is defunct. Better not try that.

Comment: Your link is from 2014. As you can read [here](http://distrowatch.com/table-mobile.php?distribution=deepin) Deepin is no longer based on Ubuntu since 2015 and is since than based on Debian.

Comment: Its is very easy to install this even in Arch Linux according to it's documentation. But Ubuntu is also Debian derivative, then why is it difficult?

Answer (score 2):

https://launchpad.net/~leaeasy/+archive/ubuntu/dde

Says, in part:

```
Important Issue:
Q: Can dde on Ubuntu 16.04?
A: Sorry, the dde depends on qt version above than 5.6.
     If you want to install dde, please upgrade to 17.04 or above.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install Deepin Desktop Environment with these commands:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leaeasy/dde
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dde
```

Once the installation is finished, log out and select the Deepin environment.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that ppa is not working.

Comment: @KashyapKansara You didn't say how you tried to use it or what happens when you do, though. If you're still looking for a solution to this, and you edit your question to include that information, then that may help.